# Asked to pay dasung in China via paypal, is it safe?

Tags: scams, paypal

I am purchasing something from dasung in China and I was asked to transfer $ to their paypal account, for which I only have their email address.  Is this safe or could the $ be lost?

Comment: Is dasung a *small* business?

Comment: The act/process itself is not inherently unsafe or illegitimate but you must be sure of your source. Like Ron said, is it a legit business, if so are they small enough that they need PayPal instead of a normally expected credit gateway. Keep in mind that with credit cards you have some inherent protections, you can always dispute a "charge" but having sent "cash" your protections are limited and while PayPal does have appeal process, based on firsthand experience you are at the mercy of someone working there deciding, so not exactly unbiased or impartial.

Answer (score 1):

PayPal itself is reasonably safe, assuming you are sure it's really PayPal. The rest of the transaction, I don't know.

Comment: The real question is whether or not OP should trust that the email address is actually linked to dasung.  We can’t answer that.

Comment: Contact the company via other channels and ask for confirmation?

Comment: Good point in @g's comment that while PayPal does provide some protections for buyers, they are different from those provided by credit card companies. See some of the other PayPal-related questions here for more on that.